# JDK error when trying to start Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have just switched from Windows7 to Windows8.1 and I'm having trouble making Android Studio work now.

I have installed Android Studio and the JDK. First I tried it out with the latest versions Android Studio `v.0.8.14` and JDK `1.8`, but I could not get it to work. I then tried to use the versions I used on my previous Windows7, and installed Android Studio `0.8.2` and JDK `1.7.0_67`, but I still can't get it to work.

The error I'm getting is:

> Failed to load JVM DLL C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\jre. If you
>   already have a 64-bit JDK installed, define JAVA_HOME variable in
>   Computer > System Properties > System Settings > Environment
>   Variables

I have set `JAVA_HOME` to my JDK path. I've tried to add `\bin` to that path, which didn't help. I've tried to add the `JDK_HOME` variable and set path to it, which didn't help either. I have also added `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\"` to my PATH variable, which also didn't help. I tried editing `studio.bat` adding a string to point to my JDK folder, which *also* didn't work.

When I check my Java from console (`cmd`) I get the msg that it works find:

> C:\Users\Igor>java -version java version "1.7.0_67" Java(TM) SE
>   Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
>   Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

Is Windows 8.1 the problem? Do I have to do something different on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this working, I put my JDK path in the Path variable as the first item. For some reason, when it's the last item it does not work.

Comment: probably there's another old java in the path as well

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

```
Control Panel>>System>>Advanced(tab)>>Environment Variables>>System Variables
New
 Variable name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
 Variable value: -Xmx512M
```

Comment: These steps are pretty unclear. You might want to tease them out a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the similar problem:

```
failed to create JVM: error code -6 
JVM PATH: .............
If you already have a 64-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer > System Properties > System Settings> Environment Variables. 
Note: Do *not* choose a Java "JRE". You need to point to a full JDK, otherwise the IDE may fail to start. See http://tools.android.com/knownissues for more details.
```

## **Solution**  for me

I solved it with the help of [Rahul Wadhai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36169968/2377343):

1) Go to `C:\users\<your_user>.AndroidStudio2.2\` and open `studio.vmoptions`

2) change `-Xmx` and `XX:MaxPermSize` to lower values(then you have currently) and try to run **AS** again. ( If it does, then you can increase the values back. )

3)  If it doesnt help, then try to rename `.AndroidStudioX.X` and then open **AS** again.

4) If it doesnt help, then you can search the problem within this android folder (using TextCrawler) , maybe somewhere in config files, there needed to change something. And then you can import settings from old folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new variable in the System variable named `JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67"`, in your `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the JDK folder path in the Environment variable:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
```

Don't use build number coming in `cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked the studio.vmoptions file when I followed a method in making it run faster and it stopped working showing the same JDK error.. I did most of the fix mentioned above and none worked for me. What worked for me though was deleting the studio.vmoptions file and everything was great again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your c:\ users\yourcomputername\ for example .AndroidStudio1.5
You will see config and system folder in it then delete the .AndroidStudio1.5  using it as example .
Go and relaunch the studio64

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me after many frustrated attempts:

go to the folder `C:\program files\Android\Android Studio\bin`

rename the file 'studio.64' to 'studio.bat' and run this file.

Comment: have made the edit rest looks fine