# How to solve an error of JVM while opening Android Studio?

Tags: jvm

I have a 64-bit processor and windows 8.And when i am opening my Android studio an error dialog box shows, written as "Failed to create JVM,JVM path:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre  if you have already have 64 bit JDK instaled,define a JAVA_HOME variable in your computer"

Answer (score 2):

Go to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions
open in notpad

-Xmx512m to -Xmx256m

-XX:MaxPermSize=250m to -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Or change:

-Xmx750m to -Xmx512m

-XX:MaxPermSize=350m to -XX:MaxPermSize=250m

Comment: I am surprised. At first, I wanted to laugh  at this solution and downvote (it doesnt refer to the problem at all). I even didnt read that seriously... After spent a hour to solve the problem, i finally tried that option................. and houh..... it solved ..  +100 !