# Android studio won't start (Unable to create JVM error)

Tags: android

Android studio was working fine till today morning but when I opened studio today it shows can't start. Shows error:

[image]

Searched the internet and SO, but couldn't find the answer. any suggestion will be appreciated.
i have set the `JAVA_HOME` path correctly. i have used studio and developed projects also using it.

Comment: set the jdk path in environment variable

Comment: show your JAVA_HOME path in question

Comment: After I do echo, I get java home C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_11

Answer (score 3):

Try this also

Delete this file : (Tested on Windows)

```
%USERPROFILE%\.AndroidStudiox.x\studio64.exe.vmoptions
```

(Keeping a backup of this file is recommended)

```
replace x.x with your Android studio version
```

*The file is used to manually set java virtual machine parameters for android studio. 
Faulty configuration might cause the software not to start.*

Answer (score 0):

You have to try to rename `.AndroidStudio2.x`.

please refer to topic - [JDK error when trying to start Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082189/jdk-error-when-trying-to-start-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Very simple trick worked for me.Though JAVA_HOME was set, it was giving an error.

To make it correct, close the error message window first, then go to environment variable settings of the system, say Edit JAVA_HOME, do not edit just say save/ok. and restart the Android Studio.

Tada... its happily working ever after :) !