# Why is android studio not opening?

Tags: android-studio

I try to open android studio but it says

```
Failed to open JVM DLL if you have JDK installed set JAVA_HOME variable....
```

- I set the `JAVA_HOME` variable, downloaded new `jdk`
- set it to that and redownloaded android studio but nothing is working.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It says to install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable
Installing it provides a "missing vcruntime140_1.dll file in bundled Java Runtime" to the Android Studio.

read - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247854802?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

buddy hopes you are doing great this crash happens when an awful java path is changed or deleted.

> This same error I already faced when the new update I downloaded to Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1

To solve this you need to change the path from the environment or you should delete the old java and download the new JDK and give the path.

> You should follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27113946/19674027 for better understanding

Happy Coding...